Numerical differentiation of sharp function while solving PDE
Sorry for a silly question.
I'm calculating a second-order partial differential equation of probability density function. My equation is a form of
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}P(x,t)=P(x,t)+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}P(x,t)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}P(x,t).
$$
I wanted to get a right-hand side using five-point stencil on a grid $\{x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ with initial function $P(x,0)=\delta(x)$. After one Euler step with time step size $dt$, the negative values of $P(x,t)$ appears up which is not feasible. I guess that five-point stencil malfunctions with the sharp function. Instead, I used two-point finite difference coefficients $\partial_x P(x,t)=(P(x+dx)-P(x))/dx$ and $\partial_x^2 P(x,t)=(P(x+2dx)-2P(x+dx)+P(x))/dx^2$ for the first step and tried five-point stencil from second step again. But still some points shows negative $P(x,t)$ values which might imply too sharpness to use 5-point stencil. Now I don't know when can I use 5-point stencil.
How do I know that the function is round enough to use five-point stencil?
Thank you.

You need to specify which stencil that you are using. Your terms "sharp" and "round" are not standard. Please edit your question and define these terms.

You are commmitting a logical fallacy when you observe that your stencil returns an undesired result and you attribute it to the spatial discretization. What reason do you have to believe that Euler is not to blame? Or the choice of time step, or the choice of spatial increment, or some property the equation that you are solving, or a combination of all of the above? Anyway, what you want to look into is called "positivity preservation". It is typically achieved, either using "monotonic stencils" (low order) or by using limiters.

Thanks @CarlChristian! Essential of my question was how can I get the numerical differentiation of delta function, or decaying function than the discretized unit in discrete space.

Positivity preservation is a good keyword to find method to check my calculation. Thanks @ekkilop
